# Avoid click triggering focusout

Tags: javascript, jquery, click, focus, jquery-focusout

i am working on the tab button functionality for my form.

I am using a plugin to customize all the selects of my form but now i am stuck on a conflict.

This is the code i have written to display my dropdown menu list using the `tab` button on the selects

```
$styledSelect.focus(function(e) {
  var dropdown = $(this).next('ul');
  dropdown.show();
});

$styledSelect.focusout(function(e) {
  var dropdown = $(this).next('ul');
  dropdown.hide();
});
```

The problem is that any click event triggers a focusout so i can not really select any option of my select tag, because the dropdown gets hidden first.

You can see the problem here http://codepen.io/Mannaio/pen/tLaup

How can i solve this problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can set up a click and focus handler and reuse the same logic for both.

```
function setFocus(e) {
  e.stopPropagation();
  $('div.select-styled.active').each(function() {
    $(this).removeClass('active').next('ul.select-options').hide();
  });
  $(this).toggleClass('active').next('ul.select-options').toggle();
};

$styledSelect.click(setFocus);

$styledSelect.focus(setFocus);
```

Updated CodePen: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/kcpqd

Comment: Thanks for the answer , there is the possibility also to keep the focus on the that select tag once i click on the dropdown?

Comment: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/kcpqd This update closes the dropdown once you tab out of the last dropdown

Comment: Your change (adding back the focusout) seemed to reintroduce the original bug. I've updated my answer with a workaround.

Answer (score 3):

Working off of Burntforest's answer (accounts for the dropdowns not closing when tabbing out):

```
function getFocus(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    hideAllLists();
    $(this).toggleClass('active').next('ul.select-options').toggle();
};

function hideAllLists() {
    $('div.select-styled.active').removeClass('active')
                                 .next('ul.select-options').hide();
}

$styledSelect.click(getFocus); 
$styledSelect.focus(getFocus);

$(document).keydown(function(e) {
   if (e.keyCode === 9)
       hideAllLists();
});
```

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/BqEkz